# ruby's net::ftp nlst('**/*') method does not work recursively on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, recursion, ftp

I'm trying to get files recursively from a windows server using ruby's `net::ftp nlst('**/*')` method. This does not work recursively on windows.

I get an error :
 `"550 The filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".`

I've seen examples of programmers using this syntax. I'm guessing this syntax does not work on windows. Why? And is there an easy way to use some sort of glob syntax even if i have to use `Dir[]`(If using `Dir[]` how do i direct it at the server's directory)?

I've tried using just one *, this gets me all files in current directories and not folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that for some reason files are being considered directories.

`File.directory?(a_known_file)` returned true when debugging. 
`ftp.chdir(a_known_file)` was thusly attempted on the file throwing an exception.
I am assuming that's also what happens in `nlst('**/*')` when using a recursive glob.

```
def is_ftp_file?(ftp, file_name)
  ftp.chdir(file_name)
  ftp.chdir('..')
  false
rescue
  true
end
```

I found the above code as an answer ([Ruby FTP Separating files from Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553939/ruby-ftp-separating-files-from-folders)) for a related question. With it i created my own recursive method.

I will leave this question open for a couple of days to see if someone can come up with a better answer(using glob syntax) or explain why this happens on windows.

Comment: I believe this function is giving me problems with the root.